# Will making a variable global solve the issue?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Whenever I define a function say funct(n), then can I assign value of n to a different variable such as m so that I can compare value of n which changes within the function with the initial value of m. Further, since I have nested and sometimes independent other functions, is there a way to make the m variable universal?

What I did is:

```
fun funct(n)= let val m=n in if (condition) then...
```

Further, here funct calls funct1 and funct1 calls funct2. The error message reads

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: m
```

for funct2

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: funct1
```

for funct1

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: funct1
```

for funct

I suppose the single correction of m would solve the wholse cascade of errors.

Comment: Can you post a complete example? It's hard to answer on an incomplete code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any identifier from scopes which are deeper than the one the identifer has been defined in. E.g.

```
fun funct(n) =
  let fun funct1(x, y, z) = if n < 1 then ...
  ...
```

In this example, `funct1` has access to `n`, which has been defined in an outer scope (namely as a parameter of `funct`).

Be careful though, in functional languages like ML, identifiers have a different meaning from those in imperative languages like C. In your example, `n` and `m` are not variables, meaning the values denoted by the identifiers will not change. You can only redefine the identifiers; however, code that uses an identifier before its redefinition will always refer to the original value of that identifier.